ERC721 safeTransferFrom reverts with no message
I'm trying to build a NFT marketplace to learn solidty but i don't understand why my code doesn't work.
Here's the relevant parts:
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import {IERC721} from "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC721.sol";
import {IERC721Receiver} from "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ReentrancyGuard{
  /**
   * @dev Prints Hello World string
   */

  address public owner;
  constructor() {
    owner= msg.sender;
  }

  receive() external payable { }
  fallback() external payable { }

  uint256 private listingFee= 0.001 ether;
  uint256 private cancellationFee= 0.001 ether;
  enum Status { Open, Sold, Cancelled, Expired }

  struct Listing {
    uint256 price;
    uint256 expiration;
    address payable seller;
    Status status;
  }
  
  mapping (address=> mapping(uint256=> Listing[])) public Listings;
function listNFT(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId, uint16 duration, uint256 price) public payable nonReentrant {
      require(price!=0, "Price must be > 0");
      require(duration!=0, "Duration must be >0");
      require(msg.value>=listingFee, "Not enough ether to pay for the listing");

      IERC721 nftContract = IERC721(nftAddress);
      
      nftContract.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
 
      Listings[nftAddress][tokenId]
        .push( Listing(price, block.timestamp + (duration * 1 days), payable (msg.sender), Status.Open) );
}

function onERC721Received() external pure returns (bytes4) {
    return IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
}

The transaction reverts when safeTransferFrom is called but no error is returned.
I also noticed that onERC721Received() is never called.
Upade:
This is the NFT contract i'm using:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721 {
    constructor()
        ERC721("MyToken", "MTK")
    {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}

Here's the remix console output:
creation of MyToken pending...
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MyToken.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...90033logs: 0hash: 0xfa4...6bb97
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0xfa4641e4967ebd15c101ba1ebd5406a0fe611cc3f8f44fcb6bff5d608316bb97
block hash  0x76fc36f2d8585cb9d8567bdcbb0ae81e94c5fbe17649c861384574f13568127a
block number    160
contract address    0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  MyToken.(constructor)
gas 1980271 gas
transaction cost    1721974 gas 
execution cost  1542298 gas 
input   0x608...90033
decoded input   {}
decoded output   - 
logs    []

creation of NFTMarketplace pending...
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: NFTMarketplace.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...90033logs: 0hash: 0x299...2b92a
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0x299ca7b9971b8ad433bbf97c0da01147bb65ed03d125690d3e8e1a5a49c2b92a
block hash  0x7339157cfe358148b0811ff9be7b4ad904c0e391c71a86f3f8460e95c1d9e0e2
block number    161
contract address    0xE5363f1b12023d5A402D551362746f684B5c6532
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  NFTMarketplace.(constructor)
gas 1423382 gas
transaction cost    1237723 gas 
execution cost  1107549 gas 
input   0x608...90033
decoded input   {}
decoded output   - 
logs    []

transact to MyToken.safeMint pending ... 
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MyToken.safeMint(address,uint256) 0xD85...81828value: 0 weidata: 0xa14...00000logs: 1hash: 0xa08...14cd6
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0xa08f7a946049dc7020ae536fd29b7905fa1cc723ab72b5c422727db2a1c14cd6
block hash  0x42de15429154a709ffaa284db0b7fa2b0a00fd57485fe473b1604f23569c6f16
block number    162
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  MyToken.safeMint(address,uint256) 0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828
gas 79867 gas
transaction cost    69449 gas 
execution cost  47889 gas 
input   0xa14...00000
decoded input   {
    "address to": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
    "uint256 tokenId": "0"
}
decoded output  {}
logs    [
    {
        "from": "0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828",
        "topic": "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
        "event": "Transfer",
        "args": {
            "0": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "1": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
            "2": "0",
            "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "to": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
            "tokenId": "0"
        }
    }
]

transact to MyToken.approve pending ... 
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MyToken.approve(address,uint256) 0xD85...81828value: 0 weidata: 0x095...00000logs: 1hash: 0x2b9...e21bd
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0x2b90ee9060e0b2452d39f3cdd5372cff88181249c94d6801bc035702b11e21bd
block hash  0x6134f09b1787de804220f624566b7b069296977540b362c116b3465bdea397a8
block number    163
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  MyToken.approve(address,uint256) 0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828
gas 56352 gas
transaction cost    49001 gas 
execution cost  27441 gas 
input   0x095...00000
decoded input   {
    "address to": "0xE5363f1b12023d5A402D551362746f684B5c6532",
    "uint256 tokenId": "0"
}
decoded output  {}
logs    [
    {
        "from": "0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828",
        "topic": "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
        "event": "Approval",
        "args": {
            "0": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
            "1": "0xE5363f1b12023d5A402D551362746f684B5c6532",
            "2": "0",
            "owner": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
            "approved": "0xE5363f1b12023d5A402D551362746f684B5c6532",
            "tokenId": "0"
        }
    }
]

transact to NFTMarketplace.listNFT pending ... 
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: NFTMarketplace.listNFT(address,uint256,uint16,uint256) 0xE53...c6532value: 1000000000000000 weidata: 0x2dd...00001logs: 0hash: 0xd4b...1b454
status  0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0xd4bcee9af9279678b5587fac19d0be48416eb7825559908e7a0ef290d261b454
block hash  0x23ec0753de1217133ccad39575aa20ba80bd27002348cddc31604d194ababd7d
block number    164
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  NFTMarketplace.listNFT(address,uint256,uint16,uint256) 0xE5363f1b12023d5A402D551362746f684B5c6532
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    78795 gas 
execution cost  56955 gas 
input   0x2dd...00001
decoded input   {
    "address nftAddress": "0xD8555E9A128C07928C1429D834640372C8381828",
    "uint256 tokenId": "0",
    "uint16 duration": 1,
    "uint256 price": "1"
}
decoded output  {}
logs    []
value   1000000000000000 wei
transact to NFTMarketplace.listNFT errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.


Are you approving the contract before calling the listNFT function?

yes, if i don't i get the error: "Address that may be allowed to operate on tokens without being their owner".

The code looks fine. We need the script you used to call it to understand where's the bug.

well, i was using remix so i don't really have any script, but i'll share the console output i get


but no error is returned

So I assume only execution reverted returned with no specific reason?
Can you double check if the nftAddress you are calling is the expected ERC721 contract?
If so and the NFTMarketplace contract is also being approved on operating this ERC721 token ID, then we might need the ERC721 code as well to do further analysis.

i added the nft contract code
